# Additional force on a scale

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, free-body-diagram

I have this problem I solved, but I don't think I understand in full detail. I think the underlying physics concept here is the change of momentum in a system where mass is changing.

A person is trying to check the mass of some amount of sugar on an electronic scale that responds instantaneously to the force applied. Scale can display data in newtons. The person is pouring sugar from a bowl at a constant rate $\sigma=0.1\frac{kg}{s}=100\frac{g}{s}$ from such a height that sugar crystals hit the scale with downward speed $u=2\frac{m}{s}$. What is the error displayed on the scale's screen (i.e. the absolute value of the difference between the weight of sugar on the scale and displayed data on the scale's screen)?

I thought about this in the following manner.
Let's imagine a single grain of sugar (mass $m_g$ with given velocity. It has momentum $p=m_{g}\cdot u$ just before the impact and the momentum will be lost in some unknown time $\Delta t$. For simplicity let's assume that the stopping force from the scale on the grain is constant in time. Hence, one can say that the stopping force is $F=\frac{m_g\cdot u}{\Delta t}$. However, the stopping time is still unknown. So I started thinking.
There are $N$ grains of sugar in $100 g$, therefore $N$ grains hit the scale (assuming the heap is not forming) every second, according to the given value of $\sigma$. Next, the expression for $F$ can be properly scaled, $F=\frac{N\cdot m_g u}{N\cdot \Delta t}$. If I change the $\frac{N m_g}{N\Delta t}$ into $\sigma$, I get $F=\sigma\cdot u $ which gives me the answer from the author's solution.

**However**, I don't understand how we know that $N\cdot \Delta t $ is exactly $1s$! For sure that expression gives the total stopping time of "one portion" ($N\cdot m_g=100 g$) of sugar, assumming they hit the scale one by one and the next one hits the scale the moment the previous one stopped fully.

I hope somebody can guide into looking up something, some concepts, or some tools, or similar easier problem that can guide me towards full deep understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about $m_g$. You are given $\frac{dm}{dt}=\sigma$, and the velocity $u$ is also constant.
Thus $F=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d(mu)}{dt} =u\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The "impact time" $\Delta t$ doesn't affect the result.  To avoid needing to define it, it helps to do things in terms of impulse instead.

The total impulse ($I = \int F \, dt$) delivered by each grain of sugar to the scale is still $m_g u$, regardless of how long each individual grain takes to come to rest. This means that the total impulse delivered to the scale by $N$ grains of sugar is $I_\text{tot} = N m_g u$.  If these $N$ grains hit the scale over a period of time $T$, then the average force on the scale over this period is $\bar{F} = I_\text{tot}/T = N m_g u/T$.  But $N m_g/T$ is just the average rate at which the mass hits the scale, i.e., $\sigma$.